# Writing a formula as Syntax in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to run a rank formula across a range of cells. I am scratching my head as to why it's not working. Lastrow is just the formula that counts the number of rows.

```
Range("B1:B" & Lastrow).Formula = "=RANK(A1,Offset(" & Chr$(36) & "A1" & Chr$(36) & "," & Lastrow & ",0))"
```

I feel like it's something wrong with Chr$(36), but when I try Chr(36) it doesn't work either. (removing these chr(36)'s and just having Offset(A1... etc) works fine).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Was being silly! `Range("B1:B" & Lastrow).Formula = "=RANK(A1,A1:Offset(" & Chr(36) & "A" & Chr(36) & "1," & Lastrow & ",0))"`

Comment: so you got it working?

Comment: Why are you using Chr(36) instead of just adding $ to the string?

Comment: It works, but thanks for suggesting '$' instead of Chr(36). I didn't think I was allowed to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to see what you want to do. The line of VBA code below will, at least, work.

```
Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=RANK(ROW(),$A1:$A$" & LastRow & ",0)"
```

Your issue seems to be with the RANK() function. It has 3 arguments, (1) the rank, (2) the range in which to find the rank and (3) Ascending/Descending. In your formula the first argument is missing and your "Offset(" & Chr$(36) & "A1" & Chr$(36) & "," & LastRow" doesn't describe a range, read as `Offset($A1$,300` with closing bracket missing.

My above formula suggests the Row number as rank, meaning 1 for Row 1, 2 for Row 2 etc. but descending, as indicated by the 3rd argument (taken from your formula) and, as second argument a range in column A between A1 and the LastRow. It probably isn't what you wanted but I hope you will be able to tweak it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I have figured it out but your suggestion of the Row() function is clever as it removes additional column for me. Thanks!